# How to change flutter application name display on phone screen?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-dependencies

How to change the application name of the flutter project displayed on phone?
I checked the file `pubspec.yaml`

```
name: flutter_app
description: A new Flutter application.
```

edited name's property, but the import package reference will also be changed, it's possible to change the application name only?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

#### Android

Open `AndroidManifest.xml` file, make below changes

```
<application
    android:label="App Name" ...> // Your app name here
```

#### iOS

Open `info.plist` file, make below changes

```
<key>CFBundleName</key>
<string>App Name</string> // Your app name here
```

Comment: These are native methods to do that. I want to know flutter handles it from a single point or not?

Comment: @PankajBansal Do you mean you wanna change name dynamically?

Comment: @CopsOnRoad No I want to know is there any common place for iOS and android where I can give app name and icon because I know different for IOS(Plist) and Android(Manifest).

Comment: @PankajBansal I am sorry as of now there is no way, you need to do it in `info.plist` and `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: For ios, updating the value of `CFBundleName` alone didn't work. I have to update `CFBundleDisplayName` value also. My app's flutter version is 2.10.3.

Answer (score 4):

To change your **application name** , you need to change it for **Android and IOS :**

You can use [**rename**](https://pub.dev/packages/rename) package to make it easy .

**Just run this command inside your flutter project root**

```
pub global run rename --appname "My application"
```

or

**Edit `AndroidManifest.xml` for Android and `info.plist` for iOS**

For **Android**, edit **only** `android:label` value in the **application** tag in file *AndroidManifest.xml* located in the folder: `android/app/src/main`

**Code:**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="Your Application Name"  //here
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity>
        <!--  -->
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

For **iOS**, edit **only** the value inside the **String** tag in file *Info.plist* located in the folder `ios/Runner` .

**Code:**

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>Your Application Name </string>  //here
</dict>
</plist>
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Do a `flutter clean` and restart your application if you have a problem.